# How to losslessly concatenate videos with different timescale (tbn)?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion

ffmpeg or mencoder says that video files must be in the same fps, resolution and format to concatenate properly.

Here is the output information about my two video files. What ffmpeg or mencoder command I must run in order to change what characteristic, in order to be possible to merge these two video files into a single video file?

```
$ ffmpeg -n -i D1_video.mp4 -i D2_video.mp4
ffmpeg version 3.4.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.18.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  WARNING: library configuration mismatch
  avcodec     configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.18.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared --enable-version3 --disable-doc --disable-programs --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libtesseract --enable-libvo_amrwbenc
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'D1_video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
  Duration: 00:21:41.61, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4525 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 4278 kb/s, 29.58 fps, 29.58 tbr, 11360 tbn, 59.17 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 239 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'D2_video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
  Duration: 00:21:58.57, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3313 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 3085 kb/s, 29.58 fps, 29.58 tbr, 29583 tbn, 59.17 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #1:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 219 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

Answer (score 0):

The timescales are different. `D1_video.mp4` has 11360 tbn. `D2_video.mp4` has 29583 tbn. These must match. Other attributes look acceptable so they can stay the same.

1. Change `D1_video.mp4` to 29583 tbn:

   ```
   ffmpeg -i D1_video.mp4 -c copy -video_track_timescale 29583 D1_video_b.mp4
   ```
2. Make `input.txt` containing:

   ```
   file 'D1_video_b.mp4'
   file 'D2_video.mp4'
   ```
3. Concatenate:

   ```
   ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -c copy output.mp4
   ```

Comment: Dear llogan, please check my newer post, and what I did. I made fps, and video and audio codecs the same ones, but stil mencoder fails. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62028849/mencoder-error-merging-two-video-files-with-same-fps-resolution-and-codec-fai

Comment: Yes, i tried to do that just now. The first video is playing normal, the 2nd one is playing without sound, and in very very slow mode in VLC (like 3-5 times slower than normal). So, this is not a proper solution. However, thank you for your time.

Comment: Question updated with ffmpeg concetrate command output which failed - it was transfered in the output video file only the 1st video file and only that.

Comment: I can even post a wetransfer link in 3-4hours if it is asked with both videos. It was a public music open/free training perfarmance in Greece.

Comment: I rencoded videos before posting your idea using: `ffmpeg -i D1_vid.mp4 -c:v libx264 -refs 3 -x264-params b-pyramid=2   -acodec aac -b:a 327680  D1_video.mp4`

Comment: Note that  `ffmpeg -i D1_video_b.mp4 -i D2_video.mp4 d_output.mp4` didnt work but it worked the concat command! Thanks

Comment: Why ffmpeg, did not produce an error report on the elements that do not match between videos that are to merged, when concat multiple videos?